koi8-r text is shown incorrectly
Here is the code that tries to output text in koi8-r single-byte encoding to the browser.
I saved it in Emacs in koi8-r:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;
no utf8;

get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    $c->res->headers->content_type('text/plain; charset=KOI8-R');

    # Respond with plain text
    $c->render(text => "Hello, World! Текст на русском однобитный.");
};

app->start;

I works but instead of "Hello, World! Текст на русском однобитный." in Firefox I see:
Hello, World! ц╢ц┘ц▀ц⌠ц■ ц▌ц│ ц▓ц∙ц⌠ц⌠ц▀ц▐ц█ ц▐ц└ц▌ц▐ц┌ц┴ц■ц▌ц≥ц┼.

After I click View - "Repair text encoding", I get:
Hello, World! ôÅËÓÔ ÎÁ ÒÕÓÓËÏÍ ÏÄÎÏÂÉÔÎÙÊ.

I seems that "Текст на русском однобитный" is being interpreted in Windows-1252 instead of koi8-r and that's why I see "ôÅËÓÔ ÎÁ ÒÕÓÓËÏÍ ÏÄÎÏÂÉÔÎÙÊ".
What is wrong? Maybe render function can't work with single byte encoding?

You face a double mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): 'Текст на русском однобитный'.encode( 'koi8_r').decode( 'latin1').encode( 'utf_8').decode( 'koi8_r') returns 'ц╢ц┘ц▀ц⌠ц■ ц▌ц│ ц▓ц∙ц⌠ц⌠ц▀ц▐ц█ ц▐ц└ц▌ц▐ц┌ц┴ц■ц▌ц≥ц┼'… Switch to UTF-8 Everywhere.

Why not save it as UTF-8? The encoding of the source file has nothing to do with what you send in a request.

@briandfoy 1 byte encoding consumes less space and is easier to process for the CPU. If I won't have any other text except Cyrillic and Latin why the overhead of 2 bytes per symbol?

Because the overhead of 2 (or 3 or 4) bytes per symbol works, and the other way doesn't. Of everything going on, including using Mojolicious and using perl, this level of optimization is irrelevant.

I can see a use for this if some consumer can only handle a particular encoding. However, if the consumer can handle UTF-8, go with that.
This works by sending raw octets with data:
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use utf8;

use Encode qw(encode);

get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    $c->res->headers->content_type('text/plain; charset=KOI8-R');

    my $message = "Hello, World! Текст на русском однобитный.";

    $c->render(data => encode('KOI8-R', $message) );
};

app->start;

First, you don't have to store your program in the encoding that you want to emit. It's easier to make the source UTF-8 and then emit something else. Not storing it as UTF-8 means you have to wrangle everything yourself, and that's going to cause problems. @JosefZ already explained this leads to the equivalent of this chain:
'Текст на русском однобитный'
    .encode( 'koi8_r')
    .decode( 'latin1')
    .encode( 'utf_8')
    .decode( 'koi8_r')

There is an encoding pragma that tells perl to assume your source is some other encoding, but quoting from its docs:

This pragma dates from the days when UTF-8-enabled editors were uncommon. But that was long ago, and the need for it is greatly diminished.

That's perl telling you to not do what you are trying to do by saving it as KOI8-R (or anything not ASCII nor UTF-8).
Second, Perl stores its strings in its internal Perl format, which is something like UTF-8. You don't have to know anything about that. However, Encode knows what to do with that when you want to encode it to something else.
Third, if you want to emit bytes (which is the result of encode), use data. The text type will re-encode, and if you are trying to control the bytes, you don't want perl sticking its fingers in your pie.
Or, you can tell Mojo to render text in some other encoding. This also works and may be useful if everything you are going to send will be not-UTF-8.
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use utf8;

use Encode qw(decode encode);

get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    $c->app->renderer->encoding('koi8-r');
    $c->res->headers->content_type('text/plain; charset=KOI8-R');

    my $message = "Text, World! Текст на русском однобитный.";

    $c->render(text => $message);
};

app->start;


try this:
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;
  
get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    $c->res->headers->content_type('text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

    # Respond with plain text
    $c->render(text => "Hello, World! Текст на русском однобитный.");
};
app->start;


The difference here is really the deletion if no utf8;, which told perl your source encoding was not to be interpreted as UTF-8. All those wide characters are then taken as literal bytes. Setting UTF-8 in Content-Type doesn't make those magically UTF-8.  That gets you the mojibake. The other new thing in this code is the addition of -signatures, after which signatures are not used. Note that Perl is slowly phasing out the combination of signatures and @_ fiddling (the shift) in the same code.
